# Nested Case when SQL Teradata

Tags: sql, nested, teradata

please I have the below data that I need to calculate the date diff between the Current_date and the Max Date for each ID for `Active` Status only and the result of the date diff will be located once beside the max date and the other records return NULL.

```
|ID  |Date  |Status   |
|----+------|---------|
|A   |1-Apr |Active   |
|A   |15-Apr|Active   |
|B   |1-Mar |Suspended|
|B   |15-Mar|Deactive |
|C   |1-Jan |Active   |
|C   |15-Jan|Active   |
```

I tried to use the below query but it duplicates the result with each date

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Date, 
    CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Active' THEN
    CASE WHEN Date = MAX(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
         THEN CURRENT_DATE - MAX(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) ELSE NULL END
ELSE NULL END AS Duration
FROM cte
ORDER BY ID, Date;
```

But I need the result to be like the below

```
|ID  |Date  |Status   |Duration|
|----+------|---------|--------|
|A   |1-Apr |Active   |NULL    |
|A   |15-Apr|Active   |19      |
|B   |1-Mar |Suspended|NULL    |
|B   |15-Mar|Deactive |NULL    |
|C   |1-Jan |Active   |NULL    |
|C   |15-Jan|Active   |109     |
```

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but why not combine both with AND =>
CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Active' AND Date = MAX(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
         THEN CURRENT_DATE - MAX(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) ELSE NULL END AS Duration

Comment: @hhoeck I tried to use AND but also it duplicates the result with each date

Comment: SELECT ID,
       DATE,
       Status,
       CASE
         WHEN STATUS = 'Active' AND RNUM = 1 THEN CURRENT_DATE - DATE
         ELSE NULL
       END AS Duration
FROM (SELECT ID,
             DATE,
             Status,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Status ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS RNUM
      FROM CTE) CTE2
ORDER BY ID,
         DATE

Comment: Unless you got multiple rows per id/date hhoeck's proposal should work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want this on the most recent row with "ACTIVE", then add in `row_number()`:

```
SELECT ID, Date, 
       (CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Active' AND
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE DESC) = 1
             THEN CURRENT_DATE - Date
        END) as Duration
FROM cte
ORDER BY ID, Date;
```

Note that your code looks like it should work, unless there are duplicate most recent dates for an `id`.  However, this version is a bit simpler, eschewing the nested `CASE` expression and the unnecessary second call to `MAX()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID,
       DATE,
       Status,
       CASE
         WHEN STATUS = 'Active' AND RNUM = 1 THEN CURRENT_DATE - DATE
         ELSE NULL
       END AS Duration
FROM (SELECT ID,
             DATE,
             Status,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID,Status ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS RNUM
      FROM CTE) CTE2
ORDER BY ID,
         DATE;
```